# Beamer: logo above the slide title

Tags: beamer, lyx

I'm making my own beamer template in LyX. On every slide, I want to place a logo and a horizontal line above the slide title. Also, I would like the line to be black.

In the LaTeX preamble I have the following:

```
\usepackage{textpos} % package for the positioning
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{500mm}(-0.8cm,-0.8cm)
\includegraphics[height=0.7cm]{Chalmers_black.eps}
\line(1,0){450}
\end{textblock*}}

% For footer
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{infolines theme}
{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}My footer line 1\vspace{0.05cm} \newline \vspace{0.1cm}My footer line 2
\end{beamercolorbox}}
\vskip0pt
}
```

This results the following slide, where the title overlaps with the logo and the horizontal line is also incorrectly placed.

[image]

How should I edit the preamble in order to have the desired output, i.e.

```
logo
horizontal line (in black)
title
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.